# Trigger to prevent deletion of tasks, or attachments, except for admins

Tags: apex, trigger, activities

How can i modify this to for System admin to bypass this trigger? I have the following, but it isn't working so i think i am missing something (Was working fine before i tried to add in the bypass admins)

```
Trigger PreventDelete on Task (before delete)
{

Id profileid=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Name ='System admin'].Id;
   if(userinfo.getProfileId()==profileid)
  {

      // bypass
  }
   else
 {
     // execute stmt
 }

for(Task tsk : Trigger.old)
{
  tsk.addError('This record cannot be deleted');
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your add error code to else part.You are executing the loop without any check on the profile

```
    Trigger PreventDelete on Task (before delete){

Id profileid=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Name ='System admin'].Id;
   if(userinfo.getProfileId()==profileid){
      // bypass
    }
   else{
            Trigger.old[0].addError('This record cannot be deleted');           
    }
}
```

Comment: In else condition why you're iterating loop over `Task` and then showing error. Instead Why don't you directly show error like this `else {tsk.addError('This record cannot be deleted');}`. If wrong, correct me.

Comment: @Lewis - Please mark it as the answers if this answers your query